# Key binding or key bindings (tech term)

Tags: technical, computing, technology

Does anyone know if the term *key binding* can be used for a combination of keys pressed, for example CTRL (Control) + SHIFT + m? Or should I use *key bindings* (plural) because there are three keys involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Key binding* is still jargon that hasn't made it to a non-technical dictionary yet.  In that context it has been defined as

> A key, or key combination, which, when pressed, causes something to happen.

Normally a key binding is a combination of keys, and is still singular. *Key bindings* is plural in the normal sense of the word. If you have two different key bindings, one for save and one for load, you use the plural.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/key_binding#:%7E:text=Noun,pause%20to%20the%20Escape%20key.)

Comment: Thank you, @jimm101. So, if I say "I added a key binding" that can mean a combination of keys. Right?

Comment: Yes. As long as their is one action triggered, it's a singular key binding. ctrl-c is a key binding for copy. On the emacs editor, C-x C-n creates a new document, and is still a single key binding even though you're hitting two keys, letting them go, and hitting two new keys. As long as there is a single action taken on any combo, it's a single key binding.